# Is the Beta distribution decomposable?

Tags: probability-distributions, st.statistics

Consider a random variable $Y$ that follows the Beta distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$:
$$
Y \sim {\rm Beta}(x | \alpha,\beta)
$$
Is it possible to decompose $Y$ as
$$
Y = X_1 + X_2
$$
for non-constant, independent random variables $X_1,X_2$?

I have searched on the internet and the book *Decomposition of random variables and vectors* from Linnik and Ostrovskii provides a negative proof for the case $\alpha + \beta < 1$. However, I am interested in the case $\alpha,\beta \geq 1$. Any information would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To cover at least a corner case: For $\alpha=\beta=1$ the answer is positive, taking $X_1 \sim U(0, 1/2)$ and $X_2$ discrete uniform over $\{0, 1/2\}$.